# Clip-path heptagon keep border-radius

Tags: css

How can I make the edge rounded? I'm creating this heptagon by https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

```css
#heptagon {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: url(https://source.unsplash.com/jupoOpYVFzw);
  background-size: cover;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 28%, 100% 72%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0 72%, 0 28%);
}
```

```html
<div id="heptagon"></div>
```

Comment: Hi Rodney, is this maybe a similar issue to this one (see the chosen answer there): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34399897/svg-polygon-rounding

Comment: @JanosVinceller Hi, I've tried add the `stroke-linejoin: round;` but it seems not working

Comment: You can't use a `polygon` here. Use a `path`.